# Error converting response to stream in Vercel AI SDK

Tags: typescript, artificial-intelligence, vercel, openai-api

I'm trying to build a really simple chatbot with vercel ai. I'm using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsyIya5PWb0 (github source code: https://github.com/GuiBibeau/exploring-vercel-ai)

I think the issue is in the route.ts or page.tsx, but I'm not completely sure.

However, for some reason when I run the program, after I type in my message and press enter, I get an error. In the terminal, it says I have this:

- error node_modules\ai\dist\index.mjs (110:10) @ AIStream
- error Failed to convert the response to stream. Received status code: 429.

I'm sure my code is correct (I checked with github) and my OpenAI key is valid.

For reference, here's my page.tsx:

```
"use client";

import { useChat } from "ai/react";

export default function Chat() {
  const { messages, input, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useChat();

  return (
    <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-md py-24 flex flex-col stretch">
      {messages.length > 0
        ? messages.map((m) => (
            <div key={m.id}>
              {m.role === "user" ? "User: " : "AI: "}
              {m.content}
            </div>
          ))
        : null}

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          className="fixed w-full max-w-md bottom-0 border border-gray-300 rounded mb-8 shadow-xl p-2"
          value={input}
          placeholder="Say something..."
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here's my route.ts:

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai-edge";
import { OpenAIStream, StreamingTextResponse } from "ai";

const config = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(config);

export const runtime = "edge";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const { messages } = await req.json();

  const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    stream: true,
    messages,
  });

  const stream = OpenAIStream(response);
  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
}
```

Does anyone know why this error is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting"). Try again after some time?

Answer (score 0):

The `AIStream` could have better error handling, but 429 status code is coming from OpenAI, which means you hit the rate limit. Your pattern seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maker sure you have credit in your [OpenAI account](https://platform.openai.com/account/billing/overview). It is a different type of subscription that ChatGPT. So, even when you are a ChatGPT subscriber, you still have to have credit on your OpenAI account to use their API (incl. ChatGPT API)

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem.
It worked after I removed the edge runtime.